# What is purpose of multiple webroles/workerroles under one application in window azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

After working with Azure since one year still i didn't find any real scenario about multiple webroles under one application.

when we'll create hosted service at that time we need to select region as well URL of application so in our solution if we have created multiple projects(webroles/wrokerroles) then this URL map to which webrole/wrokerrole application?

As a end user webrole is a application but in Azure under one application we can host mutiple webrole applications!

Can anyone explain this Azure terminology and purpose of this also please give me some real scenario/example where we require this type of terminology?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question having "multiple webroles" in one Windows Azure application, I personally do not see any specific reason for having two or more webroles in a single Application. Having two webrole in one web role will cause one role to use port 80 and some other port (8080 default) for other role.  Because you will have one single VIP to handle two web role, you can not setup port 80 on both role. In some cases you can have such functionality plugged into one single web role configured on port 80 and 8080. I can think of one example of having two or more web roles in one application where user wants to serve hundreds of users from one specific web role which is configured to port 80 with several instances however other web role which is configured on port 8080 (other non 80) to admin site with 1-2 instances. I haven personally seen rare use of having multiple web roles in one Azure application however others might have some other view on this regard.

Having web role and worker role in one Windows Azure application is very common scenario in which you can serve content through a web server configured over HTTP/HTTPS and have a worker role to do background processing without suffocating resources on web server. You can also configure internal endpoints by defining specific ports in Web and Worker role to communicate between Web role and worker roles internally over TCP endpoints. In this scenario you can have number of web role instances to handling web traffic and several instances of worker role for  background processing separately. The best example for such scenario is like having a web site where users upload video content from a web server and once the content is upload, worker role star encoding the video and when the video is encoded the video is available on web server for  users to enjoy. In real world scenario if you have 1,000,0000 users using such website, you might end up having 100s of instances of web and worker role to facilitate overall activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If we need custom DNS as per this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981933 do we need to add port with VIP to CNAME property in DNS manager?

Comment: No you don't. When setting CNAME setting with custom DNS for Azure Cloud Service, you will only provide the cloud service *.cloudapp.net setting. VIP is used with DNS A record setting but port is never used.

Comment: You CAN have multiple web roles sharing the same port. Just use host headers to disambiguate.

Comment: @AndreaColuccio lots changes happened in 20 months so downvoting an old accepted and correct answer after 20 month seems little aggresive

Answer (score 3):

Multiple Roles are useful when your application is complex and you need to scale different things in different ways.

Different Web Roles might handle two different sites that make up one application, but that scale at different patterns (for example some BusinessAppWebRole and a AdministrationAppWebRole).  Both of the apps are a part of one "system" and are deployed together and maybe even share some .DLL's or some such, but the BusinessAppWebRole might need to scale between 9am and 9pm and needs to be performing super fast for users, while AdinistrationAppWebRole might be doing some complex math or reports and needs its own scale pattern that should not impact the BusinessApp

Alternatively, you may choose to have a Website on one web role and a WCF service on another web role.  Once again, both would be a part of the same "system" and deployed together, but have different usages and scaling strategies where a need would be to keep them on separate servers

Worker Role vs. WebRole is also a great example.  Workeroles typically are background processors.  Their goal is to scale based upon amount of work left to do. Customer-facing WebRoles need to have a different scaling strategy and must not be impacted by typically heavy/busy worker roles...

HTH

Comment: We have an app where we have an administration side and an API side. The API side is used by mobile devices and the admin side only by a few users. These have very different scaling needs.

Comment: @igorek Thanks for your answer! how VIP will point out each webrole in case of i want to chose custom DNS as per this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg981933